# How you add the "div.span" replacement functionality to Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Softwares like *Sublime text* have a nice feature where you can type for instance **div.span**, press tab and it replace this immediately by **< div class="span" >**. It's a nice feature but I don't know how it is called, do you know how to add it in Visual studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zen coding (Emmet).  There's a [plugin](http://zencoding.codeplex.com/) for it.

Comment: awesome stuff I just installed Web Essentials on VS express 2013 v2 you can do it for free

Comment: yeah, it's nice.  it'll save you a lot of time and effort :)